# Cutting down the size of a fasttext bin file

Tags: deep-learning, fasttext

Currently the bin files for fastText wiki.en.bin is about 8GB. Is there a version about half the size of this? The bin files consists of the model and pretrained vectors that were generated from a large wiki corpus. Is there a smaller en. version that would make it easier for lower range machines? Loading this up is taking too much memory.

Or to get a smaller size bin file for use with fasttext, should i train my own set of fasttext vectors with a smaller set of parallel corpus?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the quantize function

```
$ ./fasttext quantize -output wiki.en
```

This will drastically reduce the size of your model without losing too much accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the native Facebook fastText library supports quantization only for the supervised models used for classification, and cannot compress unsupervised models for embedding lookup trained e.g. on wiki.

However, I have created a package [compress-fasttext](https://github.com/avidale/compress-fasttext) that is able to significantly reduce the size of unsupervised fastText models. You can read more about it in [this Medium post](https://towardsdatascience.com/compressing-unsupervised-fasttext-models-eb212e9919ca).

There are a few models of different sizes (10MB to 200MB) compressed with this package [for English and Russian](https://github.com/avidale/compress-fasttext/releases/tag/gensim-4-draft), and [a set of tiny models for 101 other languages](https://zenodo.org/record/4905385#.Ybh3O-rP3BU).